# Rank and unrank Combination with constraints

Tags: arrays, algorithm, combinations, combinatorics, ranking

I want to rank and unrank combinations with an Element distance constraint. Selected elements cannot repeated.

For example:

`n := 10` elements choose from

`k := 5` elements being choosen

`d := 3` max distance between 2 choosen elements

`1,3,5,8,9` matches the constraint

`1,5,6,7,8` dont matches the constraint

How can ranking the combination with given  distance constraint, where `1,2,3,4,5` is smaller than `1,2,3,4,6` ? Is there a way do the ranking without compute the combinations with smaller Rank?

Comment: What do you mean by "rank" and "unrank"?

Comment: Ranking means if you sort all combinations  lexicographical then the smallest get rank 0, the second smallest Rank 1, etc.  `to rank` means `combination -> rank` and `to unrank` means `rank -> combination` but without calculating all other combinations. `rank` is the index of the combination if all would be lexicographical ordered.

Comment: No selected elements cannot repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by first creating and populating a two-dimensional array, which I will call *NVT* for "number of valid tails", to record the number of valid "tails" that start at a certain position with a given value. For example, *NVT*[4][6] = 3, because a combination that has 6 in position #4 can end in 3 distinct ways: (…, 6, 7), (…, 6, 8), and (…, 6, 9).

- To populate *NVT*, start with *NVT*[*k*][…], which is just a row of all 1s. Then work your way back to earlier positions; for example, *NVT*[2][5] = *NVT*[3][6] + *NVT*[3][7] + *NVT*[3][8], because a "tail" starting at position #3 with value 5 will consist of that 5 plus a "tail" starting at position #4 with value 6, 7, or 8.
- Note that we don't care whether there's actually a valid way to *reach* a given tail. For example, *NVT*[4][1] = 3 because of the valid tails (1, 2), (1, 3), and (1, 4), even though there are no *complete* combinations of the form (…, 1, _).

Once you've done that, you can compute the rank of a combination *C* as follows:

- For position #1, count up all the valid tails starting at position #1 with a value less than *C*[1]. For example, if *C* starts with 3, then this will be *NVT*[1][1] + *NVT*[1][2], representing all combinations that start with 1 or 2.
- Then do the same for all subsequent positions. These will represent combinations that start off the same way as *C* up until a given position, but then have a lesser value at that position.
- For example, if *C* is (1, 3, 5, 8, 9), this comes out to
  0 +
  (*NVT*[2][1] + *NVT*[2][2]) +
  (*NVT*[3][1] + *NVT*[3][2] + *NVT*[3][3] + *NVT*[3][4]) +
  (*NVT*[4][1] + *NVT*[4][2] + *NVT*[4][3] + *NVT*[4][4] + *NVT*[4][5] + *NVT*[4][6] + *NVT*[4][7]) + 
  (*NVT*[5][1] + *NVT*[5][2] + *NVT*[5][3] + *NVT*[5][4] + *NVT*[5][5] + *NVT*[5][6] + *NVT*[5][7] + *NVT*[5][8]).

Conversely, you can find the combination *C* with a given rank *r* as follows:

- Create a temporary variable *rr*, for "remaining rank", initially equal to *r*.
- To find *C*[1] — the value in position #1 — count up valid tails starting at position #1, starting with the least possible value (namely 1), stopping once this would exceed *rr*. For example, since *NVT*[1][1] = 66 and *NVT*[1][2] = 27, the combination with rank 75 must start with 2 (because 75 ≥ 66 and 75 < 66 + 27). Then subtract this sum from *rr* (in this case leaving 75 − 66 = 9).
- Then do the same for all subsequent positions, making sure to keep in mind the least possible value given what was in the previous position. Continuing our example with *r* = 75, *C*[1] = 2, and *rr* = 9, we know that *C*[2] ≥ 3; and since *NVT*[2][3] = 23 > *rr*, we immediately find that *C*[2] = 3.

---

Complexity analysis:

- Space:

  - *NVT* requires *O*(*nk*) space.
  - Returning a combination as a length-*k* array inherently requires *O*(*k*) space; but if we return the combination one value at a time (by invoking a callback or printing to a console or something), then the computation itself doesn't actually depend on this array, and only requires *O*(1) extra space.
  - Aside from that, everything else can be managed in *O*(1) space; we don't need any recursion or temporary arrays or anything.
- Time:

  - Populating *NVT* takes *O*(*nkd*) time. (Note: if *d* is greater than *n*, then we can just set *d* equal to *n*.)
  - Given *NVT*, computing the rank of a given combination takes worst-case *O*(*nk*) time.
  - Given *NVT*, computing the combination with a given rank takes worst-case *O*(*nk*) time.

---

Implementation note: The details of the above are a bit fiddly; it would be easy to get an off-by-one error, or mix up two variables, or whatnot, if you don't have concrete data to look at. Since there are only 168 valid combinations for your example, I recommend generating all of them, so that you can reference them during debugging.

---

Possible additional optimization: If you expect *n* to be quite large, and you expect to do a lot of queries to "rank" and "unrank" combinations, then you might find it useful to create a second array, which I will call *NVTLT* for "number of valid tails less than", to record the number of valid "tails" that start at a certain position with a value *less than* a given value. For example, *NVTLT*[3][5] = *NVT*[3][1] + *NVT*[3][2] + *NVT*[3][3] + *NVT*[3][4], or if you prefer, *NVTLT*[3][5] = *NVTLT*[3][4] + *NVT*[3][4]. (You can do this as an in-place transformation, completely overwriting *NVT*, so it's an *O*(*nk*) pass with no additional space.) Using *NVTLT* instead of *NVT* for your queries will let you do binary search for values, rather than linear search, giving worst-case *O*(*k* log *n*) time instead of *O*(*nk*) time. Note that this optimization is even trickier than the above, so even if you intend to perform this optimization, I recommend starting with the above, getting it working perfectly, and only then adding this optimization.

Comment: Would you please show the NVT array. For me its NVT[2][1]=27 but not NVT[1][2] it has the value 50. Thanks

Comment: @TThoEinthausend: For the example in your question (*n* = 10, *k* = 5, *d* = 3), *NVT* is `[[66, 50, 31, 15, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [27, 26, 23, 17, 10, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0], [9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 6, 3, 1, 0, 0], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]`. So you're correct that NVT[2][1] = 27 and NVT[1][2] = 50.